# Let Gmap center on the users geolocation, but still load all the node markers onto the map

Tags: nodes, google-maps, location

For a website I am building I have a used a map to display all the nodes inside my country, by using a view. When the map is loaded, it shows the whole country (by standard settings in the Gmap module).

What I would like to do having this map centered on my location, but still show/load all these node markers that are spread across the map.

I manage to have the map centered on my location by using Filters and SmartIP in the view, but offcourse this limits the loaded nodes to only that location. I do not want to filter anything, just center the map. I am new to Drupal, and can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: How are you centering the map with views? Are you using the a contextual filter from the location module?

Answer (score 1):

I can clarify after my comment on your question is addressed but if I had to guess I would say you are using an nid contextual filter to center the map?

If so, that is why you aren't getting other nodes.

Alternatives are:

- Add the Global: Null contextual filter and pass the nid through that. The null contextual filter will not affect results at all.
- Keep using the nid contextual filter, but check the "Exclude" checkbox in the "More" fieldset of the filter. This will mean all nodes except the given nid will be displayed, but the given nid can still be used to center the map.

Use whichever method gives you the functionality you want.